# Sending NSData over network to other computer/device

Tags: ios, tcp, wifi, nsdata, send

I am trying to figure out how to send an NSData object to a computer/device on the network.

I have a hard time figuring out how to do this and I can barely find any examples.

I have already looked in to the Apple documentation but still no luck figuring it out.

I am on XCode 6 and iOS 8+.

What is the easiest and most straight forward way to send NSData over TCP to another device?

Comment: Why not use NSURLConnection? Pretty straightforward for me

Comment: you could check NSStream && NSStreamDelegate class in apple document.

Comment: The problem is sending the data or finding the address of the destination?

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr NSURLConnection is for HTTP only right? I need for TCP.

Comment: @Wain the problem is sending the data. Like, how do I setup a simple sender/reciever demo to test sending data from one device to another.

Comment: O, I see. Sorry for stupidity. Than yeah, you should look at NSStream. And, probably check AFNetworking - I believe it should have kind of functionality you need

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr I looked into AFNetworking but it seems to be a bit outdated. Is there an alternative to AFNetworking?

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr oops, it seems to be up to date, sorry. But it's still about HTTP.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's about HTTP. My second fault on your question +(

Comment: Well, actually, the only thing I can propose - get down to sockets, but it sounds a bit to extreme

Comment: Take a look
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html